# Should I use a hose clamp on my furnace drainage pipe?

Tags: pipe, pvc, plastic, hose

I have a drainage pipe coming from my furnace that a hose regularly connects to and drains to somewhere down into the floor. The hose unfortunately isn't in a great location and if people aren't being careful then it can be knocked off fairly easily. I was wondering if I took a hose clamp would help at all. My concern right now is that it could maybe damage the plastic, maybe PVC pipe coming out of the furnace.

Does anyone know of the proper way to get a better connection between the pipe and the hose.

The link for the picture of the pipe is below. The pipe has a red circle around the end of it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proper to put a hose clamp on a connection like that as often the barbs aren't sufficient especially after it's come off a few times.  If you're worried about damaging the fitting from the furnace just add another fitting after it and secure it the the furnace or floor, etc.  Then your standalone fitting will be the one that gets damaged if somebody kicks it hard.

Comment: A metal hose clamp will work fine - just make sure that you only tighten it enough to hold the two pipes together snugly.  If you over tighten the clamp, then you risk damaging the pipes.

Answer (score 0):

If the hose is being knocked in to frequently enough to have it fall off, I would suggest that your problem is the knocking, not the tightness of the connection.

Putting a hose clamp on there will not stop the bumping. But it will transfer the energy of the knock to the entire assembly. **Someday, instead of just ripping off the hose, you're going to break that fitting.**

Fix the problem correctly: Lengthen the hose, reroute the hose, or build something to protect the fitting or the whole unit (frame in the furnace?).

Comment: Thanks, I suggested something like this originally to my landlord and they didn't want to go to the work of doing it.

I won't be living here for long I'd just prefer not to have further water damage in the ceiling in the place where I live.